# What is the grammar to have parentheses take place of linebreaks?

Tags: antlr4

For example, I'm attempting to write a grammar to parse DNS zone files.  The resource records are normally separated by newlines.  However, a record can be broken across multiple lines by using parentheses.  For example:

`record1 part1 part2 part3 part4`

or

`record1 part1 ( part 2
part3
part4
)`

I can't come up with how to allow for the parentheses to exist at any place within a record.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (not thoroughly tested).

grammar:

```
grammar dns;


file : (record|NL)+ EOF ;


record : recordName recordPart+ (NL|EOF)
       ;

recordName : Something;

recordPart
    :   '(' recordPartOrNewLine+ ')'
    |   Something
    ;

recordPartOrNewLine
    :   NL
    |   recordPart
    ;

Something : [a-zA-Z0-9:.]+; // adjust!
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
NL : ('\r'? '\n')|'\r';
Comment : ';' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
```

test case (from wikipedia):

```
example.com.       1800  IN  SOA  ns1.example.com. mailbox.example.com. (
                                            100   ; Seriennummer
                                            300   ; Refresh Time
                                            100   ; Retry Time
                                            6000  ; Expire Time
                                            600   ; negative Caching Zeit
                                           )
 example.com.       1800  IN  NS ns1.example.com.

 ns1.example.com.   1800  IN  A    172.27.182.17
 ns1.example.com.   1800  IN  AAAA 2001:db8::f:a
 www.example.com.   1800  IN  A    192.168.1.2
 www.example.com.   1800  IN  AAAA 2001:db8::1:2
```

result (large image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Uqg.png)):

[image: the parse tree]